# Vertically align element with 1/3 space above 2/3 space below

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I have a "hero image" filling the height and width of the viewport. Inside this `div` there is a heading. I would like the heading to be vertically aligned so that any available space is one-third above and two-thirds below.

For example:
Hero image = 1000px high. H1 = 400 px high. So space above would = 200px
Space below = 400px

It is a responsive layout so I don't know the height of the hero image or the heading.

Vertically centring using Flexbox is easy, but I need more space below.
Can anyone suggest me in the right directions?

Here's my code so far. Please note I've not used Flex before so I don't really know what I'm doing.

```
.hero_image {
    min-height:100vh;
    background-color:yellow;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    }

.hero_image h1 {
    font-size:72px;
    padding-top:20px;
    }

<div class="hero_image">
    <h1>Heading <br>more text <br>last bit of text</h1>
</div>
```

Here's a link to the JSFiddle example
https://jsfiddle.net/yvf6tgh8/2/

Comment: Hello. Can you share your code? ([mcve])

Comment: we cannot hwlp you without checking your code..please add working code snippet or jsfiddle link. thanks

Comment: Also, I think an image of your wanted layout would be helpful. (make it with paint of whatever)

Comment: @user2991837 Provide a sample code it will help to solve the issue or Use flexbox align-content: space-between;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `hero_image` a *column* `flexbox` with *psuedo elements*:

- give `flex: 1` to `before`, and
- `flex: 2` to `after` to get the effect.

See demo below:

```css
.hero_image {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;  /* ADDED */
}

.hero_image h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: #fff; /* For Illustration */
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.hero_image:after { /* ADDED */
  flex: 2;
  content: '';
}
.hero_image:before { /* ADDED */
  flex: 1;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="hero_image">
  <h1>Heading <br>more text <br>last bit of text</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To handle the layout part I would use CSS Grid:

> CSS Grid Layout excels at dividing a page into major regions or defining the relationship in terms of size, position, and layer, between parts of a control built from HTML primitives.
>
> Like tables, grid layout enables an author to align elements into columns and rows. However, many more layouts are either possible or easier with CSS grid than they were with tables. For example, a grid container's child elements could position themselves so they actually overlap and layer, similar to CSS positioned elements.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

[Try it online!](https://jsfiddle.net/Ladzwtb7/)

```css
.hero_image {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto 2fr; /* here is the fun */
}

.hero_image>.content {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.hero_image h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

/* just to show margin */
.hero_image>div:first-child,
.hero_image>div:last-child {
  background: red;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero_image">
  <div></div>
  <div class="content">


    <h1>Heading <br>more text <br>last bit of text</h1>
  </div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `calc(33% - <headinghieght>)`, but you would need to know the `headingHieght` for that.

You could try something like this:

```css
#container1 {
    /*hieght : 100px;*/
    border : 2px solid blue; 
}

#headingContainer {
    margin-top: 33%;
    margin-bottom: 66%;
    hieght : 40px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h1>The calc() Function</h1>

<div id = "container1">
text
    <div id = "headingContainer">HEADING</div>
    text 2
</div>
```